# How can I store a variable in another file?

Tags: c++, file, save

I am currently programming in C++. I want my program to store an int in a file so that when i close the program and open it again to take the value of the stored int. How can I do it?

Comment: [A Tour of C++](http://www.amazon.com/Tour-C-Depth-ebook/dp/B00F8CWGOS), Chapter 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [std::fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int myint;

int main() {
    // when entering app:
    std::ifstream fs("data.txt");
    if ( fs ) {
        fs >> myint;
    }
    fs.close();

    std::cout << myint;
    myint++;

    // when exiting app:
    std::ofstream fs2("data.txt");
    fs2 << myint;
}
```

Comment: Error: "variable std::fstream fs has initializer but incomplete type std::fstream fs("data.txt");

Comment: @PanagiotisIatrou you need to add includes: `#include <fstream>` and `#include <iostream>`